# Safer TypeScript - what are the differences to normal TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Microsoft Research offers a new TypeScript compiler variant called **Safer TypeScript**:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/b250c887-2b79-4413-9d7a-5a5a0c38cc57/

I could not find any documentation on it, and I was unable to install it into my TypeScript 1.0 system, since it requires TypeScript 0.9.5.

**What are the differences between *TypeScript* and *Safer TypeScript*?**

Comment: I've been wondering the same think. The readme doesn't explain it either :)

Comment: Might be worth keeping an eye on [this CodePlex discussion](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/550351). I tried running a diff with 0.9.5 and the majority of changes seem to be under `src\compiler\typecheck\sound\ ` and `src\compiler\typecheck\tsStar.ts`. It's a bit hard to get a proper diff because a bunch of files just had their line endings changed.

Comment: this site says a bit about it incl a overview ppt http://rise4fun.com/FStar/tutorial/tsStar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that TS* features runtime type checking as well as static type checking, whereas standard TypeScript is only a design and compile time feature.

This means plain JavaScript code that calls your TS* code will receive type errors when passing invalid types from untrusted code. The general idea is to prevent security problems which are often caused by attacks based on unchecked types.

More information can be found here:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/nswamy/papers/gradual-typing-embedded-securely-in-javascript-draft.pdf

I have also written a [slightly less detailed summery of TS*](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201407/Blog/What-Is-TS%2a-and-How-Is-It-Safer-TypeScript/).